# Why React useState with functional update form is needed?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm reading [React Hook documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) about functional updates and see this quote:

> The ”+” and ”-” buttons use the functional form, because the updated
>   value is based on the previous value

But I can't see for what purposes functional updates are required and what's the difference between them and directly using old state in computing new state.

**Why functional update form is needed at all for updater functions of React useState Hook?** **What are examples where we can clearly see a difference (so using direct update will lead to bugs)?**

For example, if I change this example from documentation

```
function Counter({initialCount}) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount);
  return (
    <>
      Count: {count}
      <button onClick={() => setCount(initialCount)}>Reset</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)}>+</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount - 1)}>-</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

to updating `count` directly:

```
function Counter({initialCount}) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount);
  return (
    <>
      Count: {count}
      <button onClick={() => setCount(initialCount)}>Reset</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>+</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}>-</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

I can't see any difference in behaviour and can't imagine case when count will not be updated (or will not be the most recent). Because whenever count is changing, new closure for `onClick` will be called, capturing the most recent `count`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

State update is asynchronous in React. So it is possible that there would be old value in `count` when you're updating it next time. Compare, for example, result of these two code samples:

```
function Counter({initialCount}) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount);
  return (
    <>
      Count: {count}
      <button onClick={() => setCount(initialCount)}>Reset</button>
      <button onClick={() => {
        setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1); 
        setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)}
      }>+</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

and

```
function Counter({initialCount}) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount);
  return (
    <>
      Count: {count}
      <button onClick={() => setCount(initialCount)}>Reset</button>
      <button onClick={() => {
        setCount(count + 1); 
        setCount(count + 1)}
      }>+</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is a different case. update function is considered async meaning you shouldn't expect immediate value change for count after setClount call and, thus can't rely on that new value. I get it, but that is a different use case than mine. What's problem with replacing state once with new, which is based on old (as most people do)

Comment: This is exactly the reason - user can click on + and - before the rerender of the component or click on the + twice very quick and in the second call the value of `count` would be wrong (not updated).

Comment: Yes, I think I have to agree with that possible scenario

Comment: @AlexGessen, assume I click on + rapidly twice. Initial value is 0. The count should increment to 2 i.e, 0 -> 1 and then 1 -> 2. Without the functional updater form, there is a chance that when the second setCount(count + 1) is being executed, the count has not been updated to 1 yet, so it sets count to 0 + 1, using the old value of count - 0.

In a similar situation but with the functional updater, does that mean that when the 2nd setCount takes place (setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)), prevCount here will be updated even if count itself still might not be updated?

Comment: What really confuses me is that their hooks hello world at: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html  just does `onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}`. Giving a wrong hello world is evil!

Comment: Clicking fast will _not_ mess up your state, and the Hooks hello world is _not_ wrong. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73115899/388033

Answer (score 29):

I stumbled into a need for this recently. For example let's say you have a component that fills up an array with some amount of elements and is able to append to that array depending on some user action (like in my case, I was loading a feed 10 items at a time as the user kept scrolling down the screen. the code looked kind of like this:

```
function Stream() {
  const [feedItems, setFeedItems] = useState([]);
  const { fetching, error, data, run } = useQuery(SOME_QUERY, vars);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      setFeedItems([...feedItems, ...data.items]);
    }
  }, [data]);     // <---- this breaks the rules of hooks, missing feedItems

...
<button onClick={()=>run()}>get more</button>
...
```

Obviously, you can't just add feedItems to the dependency list in the useEffect hook because you're invoking setFeedItems in it, so you'd get in a loop.

functional update to the rescue:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      setFeedItems(prevItems => [...prevItems, ...data.items]);
    }
  }, [data]);     //  <--- all good now
```

Comment: This is the answer i need... Was dealing with merging an array

Answer (score 19):

The [“state update is asynchronous in React” answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57828519/388033) is misleading, as are some comments below it. My thinking was also wrong until I dug into this further. You are right, this is rarely needed.

The key idea behind functional state updates is that state you depend on for the new state might be stale. How does state get stale? Let’s dispel some myths about it:

- **Myth:** State can be changed under you during event handling.

  - **Fact:** The ECMAScript event loop only runs one thing at a time. If you are running a handler, nothing else is running alongside it.
- **Myth:** Clicking twice fast (or any other user action happening quickly) can cause the second handler to run with stale state.

  - **Fact:** React is guaranteed to *not* batch updates across more than one user-initiated event. This is true even in React 18, which does more batching than previous versions. You can rely on having a render in between event handlers.

[From the React Working Group](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/21):

> Note: React only batches updates when it’s generally safe to do. For example, React ensures that **for each user-initiated event like a click or a keypress, the DOM is fully updated before the next event.** This ensures, for example, that a form that disables on submit can’t be submitted twice.

## How does that work? 2 quick clicks = 2 runs of the same handler, right?

@Ich raises a good question in the comments. Even if you re-render in between handling one event and the next, aren't they both using the same handler referencing the same state, since they originated from the same render?

This involves a detail of React event handling that they don't talk about often. It's alluded to in the [React 17 release notes](https://legacy.reactjs.org/blog/2020/10/20/react-v17.html#changes-to-event-delegation).

In React 17, event handlers are no longer registered on `document`, but on the root node. I remember reading this and being confused. Why were event handlers on the `document` in the first place? Why, when we write `<button onClick="...">`, is the handler *not* on the `button` DOMElement?

The answer seems to be (among other things) that React cannot safely run the handler immediately. In fact, it doesn't necessarily know yet which handler to run, if any! [This gist by romain-trotard](https://gist.github.com/romain-trotard/76313af8170809970daa7ff9d87b0dd5) goes into the implementation details.

### Long story short

No matter how many `onClick`s you have in your tree, React only registers a single `click` handler, at the top of the tree. And that handler is just a shim that dispatches the event into a queue within React.

That way React can handle events at its own pace. Each render can only handle a maximum of 1 user-initiated event. Others on the queue have to wait for the next render, or the one after that, etc etc. That way, they each get a fresh handler.

### Example

Suppose you have a button that increments a state. You have a turbo mouse that clicks every 1 ms and you hammer that button 10 times before the next render.

React puts 10 click events on its event queue. It dequeues one of them and handles it, causing a re-render.

Once the re-render is finished, React notices the queue isn't empty and dequeues the next one and handles it, with a *new* handler that uses the new state. It re-renders again.

This repeats until the queue is empty. In the end there are 10 renders and 10 *different* handlers with *different* state closures.

## Ok, React tries really hard to prevent stale state. So, when DO you get stale state?

Here are the main 3 cases I can think of:

### Multiple state updates in the same handler

This is the case already mentioned where you set the same state multiple times in the same handler, and depend on the previous state. As you pointed out, this case is pretty contrived, because this clearly looks wrong:

```
  <button
    onClick={() => {
      setCount(count + 1);
      setCount(count + 1);
    }}
  >+</button>
```

A more plausible case is calling multiple functions that each do updates on the same state and depend on the previous state. But that’s still weird, it’d make more sense to do all the calculations then set the state once.

### Async state updates in a handler

For example:

```
  <button
    onClick={() => {
      doSomeApiCall().then(() => setCount(count + 1));
    }}
  >+</button>
```

This is not so obviously wrong. The state can be changed in between you calling `doSomeApiCall` and when it resolves. In this case, the state update really is async, but *you* made it that way, not React!

The functional form fixes this:

```
  <button
    onClick={() => {
      doSomeApiCall().then(() => setCount((currCount) => currCount + 1));
    }}
  >+</button>
```

### Updating state in useEffect

[G Gallegos's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59712281/388033) pointed this out for `useEffect` in general, and [letvar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61770257/388033) pointed this out for `useEffect` with `requestAnimationFrame`. If you're updating state based on previous state in `useEffect`, putting that state in the dependency array (or not using a dependency array) is a recipe for infinite loops. Use the functional form instead.

## Summary

You don’t need the functional form for state updates based on previous state, as long as you do it 1. in a user-triggered-event handler 2. once per handler per state and 3. synchronously. If you break any of those conditions, you need functional updates.

Some people might prefer to always use functional updates, so you don’t have to worry about those conditions. Others might prefer the shorter form for clarity when it’s safe to do so, which is true for many handlers. At that point it’s personal preference / code style.

## Historical note

I learned React before Hooks, when only class components had state. In class components, “multiple state updates in the same handler” doesn’t look so obviously wrong:

```
  <button
    onClick={() => {
      this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
      this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
    }}
  >+</button>
```

Since state is an instance variable instead of a function parameter, this looks fine, unless you know that `setState` batches calls when in the same handler.

In fact, in React <= 17, this would work fine:

```
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  }, 1000);
```

Since it’s not an event handler, React re-renders after each `setState` call.

React 18 introduces batching for this and similar cases. This is a useful performance improvement. There is the downside that it breaks class components that rely on the above behavior.

## References

- [React Working Group discussion](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/21)
- [React 17 release notes](https://legacy.reactjs.org/blog/2020/10/20/react-v17.html#changes-to-event-delegation)
- [romain-trotard gist on React event handling](https://gist.github.com/romain-trotard/76313af8170809970daa7ff9d87b0dd5)
- [ehab’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65306828/388033), which also mentions the two cases where functional updates are needed.

Comment: I still don't quite get it, for `<button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>+</button>` , the first click make a state change, since react state update is async, let's say it is held for 100 millisecond before it is "commited", if my second click is quick enough and make a second state change, and this change still refer to the stale `counter`  (because it is hasn't been updated)

Comment: @Ich React guarantees that won't happen. According to the Working Group, your scenario would go like this: Click at 0 ms, handling starts, click at 50 ms, first click's state change causes a re-render at 100 ms, NOW the second click is handled (100+ ms). That is, they take pains to ensure everything the first click changed is re-rendered before they even start handling the second click. In other words, they guarantee synchronizing the state before handling the next user-initiated event. Those times are long too, most renders are <20 ms.

Comment: @Ich I edited the post with a more comprehensive explanation. Had to look up some stuff to figure out what the full answer was. Good question!

Answer (score 10):

I have answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65277471/what-is-the-use-of-functional-syntax-of-setstate-in-react-functional-components/65279245#65279245) like this and it was closed because this was the canonical question - that i did not know of, upon looking the answers i decided to repost my answer here since i think it adds some value.

If your update depends on a previous value found in the state, then you should use the functional form. If you don't use the functional form in this case then your code will break sometime.

**Why does it break and when**

React functional components are just closures, the state value that you have in the closure might be outdated - what does this mean is that the value inside the closure does not match the value that is in React state for that component, this could happen in the following cases:

1- async operations ([In this example](https://xzbsm.csb.app/) click slow add, and then click multiple times on the add button, you will later see that the state was reseted to what was inside the closure when the slow add button was clicked)

```
const App = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      <p>counter {counter} </p>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setCounter(counter + 1);
        }}
      >
        immediately add
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setTimeout(() => setCounter(counter + 1), 1000);
        }}
      >
        Add
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

2- When you call the update function multiple times in the same closure

```
const App = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      <p>counter {counter} </p>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setCounter(counter + 1);
          setCounter(counter + 1);
        }}
      >
        Add twice
      </button>
   
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another use case for using functional updates with `setState` - `requestAnimationFrame` with react hooks. Detailed information is available here - https://css-tricks.com/using-requestanimationframe-with-react-hooks/

In summary, handler for `requestAnimationFrame` gets called frequently resulting in incorrect `count` value, when you do `setCount(count+delta)`. On the other hand, using `setCount(prevCount => prevCount + delta)` yields correct value.