# Difference between using the arrow function and normal function inside useEffect in the following code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-hooks, arrow-functions

I am new to React js and I am implementing the useEffect for the first time in my code. I followed few tutorials and they have done things differently as follows

**Case l:**

```
function App() {

  const[counter,setCounter] = useState(0);
  const[toggle,setToggle] = useState(false); 

  const incrementer = () =>{
    // counter+=1
    setCounter(counter + 1);    
    console.log(counter)
  };

  const toggler = () =>{
    setToggle((toggle) => !toggle);
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 className = {toggle ? 'active' : ''} >Hello world!!</h1>
      <h1>{counter}</h1>
      <h1>{abc}</h1>
      <button onClick={incrementer} >Click</button>
      <button onClick={toggler}>Toggle Here</button>     
      
      
      <div className="home">
        <h1>{Date.time}</h1>
        <Nav/> 
        <Tweets/>
      </div>    
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here inside the incrementer function, I am just using counter+1 and it gives the required result and makes sense. It increases the count by 1 on every click.

**Now case 2:**

```
function App() {  

  const[counter,setCounter] = useState(0);
  const[toggle,setToggle] = useState(false);
  

  const incrementer = () =>{
    
    setCounter(() => counter+1);
    console.log(counter)
  };

  const toggler = () =>{
    setToggle((toggle) => !toggle);
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 className = {toggle ? 'active' : ''} >Hello world!!</h1>
      <h1>{counter}</h1>
      <h1>{abc}</h1>
      <button onClick={incrementer} >Click</button>
      <button onClick={toggler}>Toggle Here</button>    
          
      <div className="home">
        <h1>{Date.time}</h1>
        <Nav/> 
        <Tweets/>
      </div>    
    </div>
  );
}
```

In this case, inside the incrementer function, it is using what seems like an arrow function. I assume it is using function inside the function. Also, it is not passing anything as () is empty. How the count is increasing here. I am confused.

Also inside the toggler function, I can write abc or any variable instead of toggle and it works. How??

**Update**

Ok my main confusion is in this code.

```
const incrementer = () =>{
    // counter+=1
    setCounter((kkk) => kkk + 1);
    // setCounter(() => counter+1);
    console.log(counter)
  };
```

This function works as well. How is this kkk value is getting the value of counter=0. Shouldnt we be writing counter instead of kkk??

Comment: "*it is using what seems like an arrow function.*" - yes. But an unnecessary one - it always returns a constant value. "*I assume it is using function inside the function*" - not sure what you mean?

Comment: "*I can write abc or any variable instead of toggle and it works. How?*" - it's a function parameter. You get to name it, the caller of the function does not care.

Comment: For you first reply, isnt setCounter one function and () is another function without name??

Comment: Yes, `setCounter` is a function, `() => counter+1` is a function, and so are `incrementer` or `App`.

Comment: that means () => counter+1 is a function inside setCounter function . A function inside another function. is that true??

Comment: A function that is passed as an argument to a call of a function. I wouldn't call that "*a function inside a function*" - I  would use that phrase to say "`incrementer` is defined inside `App`".

Comment: You'll want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57828368/why-react-usestate-with-functional-update-form-is-needed btw for the difference between the two `setState` calls. Notice this has *nothing* to do with arrow functions vs normal functions.

Answer (score 1):

Not only react hooks could use arrow functions in this way, but almost all cases in Javascript. Maybe we could have explanation in [Comparing traditional functions to arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#comparing_traditional_functions_to_arrow_functions)

Comment: I have added the update @Chris. Can you have a look at it??

Comment: It is about [Functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates).
If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can pass a function to setState. The function will receive the previous value, and return an updated value.