# Increase the quantity of an object in an array Javascript ,React, RecoilJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recoiljs

when checking it in console the result is fine, but if replace that array in setCart its not happening , RecoilJS

```
const cartState=[
    { id:1, productName:'Apple',price:100,quantity:1}
    { id:2, productName:'Cherry',price:70,quantity:1}
    { id:3, productName:'Orange',price:60,quantity:1}
    { id:4, productName:'Grapes',price:69,quantity:1}
]

const [cart, setCart] = useRecoilState(cartState)
```

object is { id:4, productName:'Grapes',price:69,quantity:1}

```
const addToCart =(object) => {
        
            if(!cart.includes(object))
            {
                setCart([...cart, object])  
            }else 
            {
                let f= cart.map(items=>
                        {
                            if(items.id==object.id)
                            {
                                return {...items, quantity:items.quantity+ 1}
                            }
                            return items
                        })
                      
                        setCart(f)
                    
         }       
                    
}
```

Comment: `!cart.includes(object)` - you can't check an object like this. You'd have to target a property value like `id` with something like `findIndex`,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

`Array.prototype.includes` basically uses shallow reference equality. Primitives and String types are ***always*** equal to themselves by value, but objects ***must*** refer to the exact same reference in memory in order for `.includes` to work for them. This is hardly ever the case in React though when the ***new*** item being added to the cart is typically going to be a ***new*** object as well.

It is always safer to match objects by specific properties.

## Solution

Search and match by the cart item ids. If *some* item in the cart has a matching `id` property, then update the cart, otherwise add the new item to the cart array.

I suggest to also use functional state updates to correctly update from the previous state, not any cart state closed over in any scopes. These can sometimes be stale references, especially if `addToCart` is called in any loops to add multiple items.

```
const addToCart = (newItem) => {
  if (cart.some(item => item.id === newItem.id)) {
    setCart(cart => cart.map(item => item.id === newItem.id
      ? { ...item, quantity: item.quantity + 1 }
      : item,
    ));
  } else {
    setCart(cart => [...cart, newItem]);
  }                 
}
```

Comment: For OP's reference, see the various answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57828368/12162258) about the need for/uses of functional state updates