# useState variables not retaining values assigned to them after api call - React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks

**Edited**

I am trying to make a form that will enable the user to edit an existing citation. The citation is pulled from the backend with an api call. I then assign the values grabbed from the api to the state variables. These state variables is passed as props to the form jsx where they are used in the `value` prop of the input field. But for some reason the values assigned to state is not retained by the state and it goes back to its initial state values. I am adding the code as to how the component looks like

```
const EditEnterCitation = () => {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

  // getting params from the url to pass to the functions
  const cat = searchParams.get("cat");
  const { id } = useParams();

  // state to pass to the value prop in the form input
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    institution_name: "0",
    judge_name: "",
    case_no: "",
    apelLate_type: "0",
    law: "",
    point_of_law: "0",
    party_name_appelant: "",
    party_name_respondent: "",
    advocate_petitioner: "",
    advocate_respondent: "",
    judgements: "",
    date_of_order: "",
    headnote: "",
    references: "",
    equivalent_citations: "",
    title: "",
  });
 
  // state to for select buttonn in the form
  const [instName, setInstName] = useState([]);

  const [lawChoiceOptions, setlawChoiceOptions] = useState([]);

  const [pointOfLawOptions, setPointOfLawOptions] = useState([]);

  const [appealateType, setAppealateType] = useState([]);

  // getting the choices for select from backend 
  const allChoices = useQuery(
    ["allChoices", cat],
    () => getAllChoices(cat),

    {
      enabled: cat !== null,
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
      onSuccess: (response) => {
        // setting law choices
        if (response.data.law) {
          let arr = response.data.law.map((element, index) => {
            return { value: element.law_name, label: element.law_name };
          });
          setlawChoiceOptions(arr);
        }
        // setting point of law options
        setPointOfLawOptions(response.data.pol);

        // setting appealate type
        setAppealateType(response.data.appeal);

        // setting ins choices
        if (response.data.ins.length) {
          setInstName(response.data.ins);
        } else {
          let court_names = [];

          let tribunal_name = [];

          if (response.data.ins.ins_court.length > 0) {
            court_names = response.data.ins.ins_court;
          }

          if (response.data.ins.ins_tribunal.length > 0) {
            tribunal_name = response.data.ins.ins_tribunal;
          }

          let ins_names = court_names.concat(tribunal_name);

          setInstName(ins_names);
        }
      },
    }
  );

  // function to get default values of the citation
  const getDefaultValues = useQuery(
    ["detailCitation", id],
    () => detailCitation(cat, id),
    {
      enabled: allChoices.isFetched === true,
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
      onSuccess: (response) => {
        setFormData({
          institution_name: response.data.institution_name,
          judge_name: response.data.judge_name,
          case_no: response.data.case_no,
          apelLate_type: response.data.apelLate_type,
          law: response.data.law,
          point_of_law: response.data.point_of_law,
          party_name_appelant: response.data.party_name_appelant,
          party_name_respondent: response.data.party_name_respondent,
          advocate_petitioner: response.data.advocate_petitioner,
          advocate_respondent: response.data.advocate_respondent,
          judgements: response.data.judgements,
          date_of_order: response.data.date_of_order,
          headnote: response.data.headnote,
          references: response.data.references,
          equivalent_citations: response.data.equivalent_citations,
          title: response.data.title,
        });
      },
    }
  );

  // handling form data change for some fields
  const handleFormDataChange = (e) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  // handling form data change for the judgement
  const handleJudgementData = (data) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, judgements: data });
  };

  const handlePartyAppealData = (data) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, party_name_appelant: data });
  };

  const handlePartyRespondData = (data) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, party_name_respondent: data });
  };

  // handling data change of the law choices
  const handleOnChangeLaw = (selectedOption) => {
    let newArray = [];

    selectedOption.map((element) => {
      newArray.push(element.value);
    });

    setFormData({ ...formData, law: newArray.toString() });
  };

  // hadling sumbimission of citation
  const handleFormDataSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      setProgress(80);
      let response = await addCitation(cat, formData);
      if (response.status === 201) {
        toastNotification(
          `Citation Uploaded to ${cat.toUpperCase()}`,
          `success`
        );
        setProgress(100);
        goToTop();
      } else {
        toastNotification(`Server Error. Could not upload citation`, `error`);
        setProgress(100);
      }
    } catch (error) {}
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.count("formData Appearing");
    console.log(formData);
  });

  return (
    <>
      <LoadingBar
        color="red"
        progress={progress}
        onLoaderFinished={() => setProgress(0)}
        height={4}
      />
      <Helmet>
        <title>Enter Citation</title>
      </Helmet>
      <Wrapper>
        <FormContainer onSubmit={handleFormDataSubmit}>
          <EditInsFormElements
            cat={cat}
            handleFormDataChange={handleFormDataChange}
            formData={formData}
            handleJudgementData={handleJudgementData}
            handleOnChangeLaw={handleOnChangeLaw}
            instName={instName}
          />
          <EditOtherFormElements
            cat={cat}
            handleFormDataChange={handleFormDataChange}
            formData={formData}
            handleJudgementData={handleJudgementData}
            handleOnChangeLaw={handleOnChangeLaw}
            lawChoiceOptions={lawChoiceOptions}
            pointOfLawOptions={pointOfLawOptions}
            appealateType={appealateType}
            handlePartyAppealData={handlePartyAppealData}
            handlePartyRespondData={handlePartyRespondData}
          />

          <FormFooter>
            <UploadBtn disabled={disableSubmit()} type="submit">
              Upload Citation
            </UploadBtn>
          </FormFooter>
        </FormContainer>
      </Wrapper>
    </>
  );
};
```

the jsx inside the EditInsFormElements and EditOtherFormElements looks like this

```
 <label className="required-field" htmlFor="apelLate_type">
          Apellate Type*
        </label>
        <select
          name="apelLate_type"
          id="apelLate_type"
          value={formData.apelLate_type}
          onChange={handleFormDataChange}
          required
        >
          <option value="0" disabled hidden>
            Select
          </option>
          {appealateType &&
            appealateType.length &&
            appealateType.map((element, index) => {
              return (
                <option key={index} value={element.appealate_type}>
                  {element.appealate_type}
                </option>
              );
            })}
        </select>
 <label className="required-field" htmlFor="case_no">
          Case No*
        </label>
        <TextArea
          name="case_no"
          id="case_no"
          value={formData.case_no}
          onChange={handleFormDataChange}
          required
        />
  <label className="required-field" htmlFor="title">
          Title*
        </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="title"
          value={formData.title}
          onChange={handleFormDataChange}
          required
        /> ....
```

And the state behaviour in the console that I have produced using useEffect is attached below

[image]

**Question**
Why is this alternating behaviour seen in the console is caused and how to rectify it so that the state retains the values grabbed and assigned from the backend.

Comment: There's not enough information to debug here... Where in your code are your `console.log()` lines? What does `EditInsFormElements` and `EditOtherFormElements` do with `formData`? What does `handleFormDataChange` look like?

Comment: @Phil I have added the codes that you wanted and handleformDataChange is just an onchange function used for forms. But the concern here is I am not able to assign data to the state variables.

Comment: What makes you think `handleFormDataChange` isn't necessary to answering this question? It's highly likely you're using `setFormData()` incorrectly

Comment: @Phil Perhaps my question is unclear to you. What I am saying here is I want to prefill the forms with data that I have grabbed from the api. I cannot prefill it because of the wierd behaviour shown in console. The data is not retained by the state. FormDataChange is not in picture here at all.

Comment: Without a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), this is impossible to answer. Also, what version of React Query are you using?

Comment: Also, where do `cat` and `id` come from? Is `id` state? Does it change at all?

Comment: @Phil ```cat``` and ```id``` are params that come from the url which I pass in the function to get data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251851/discussion-between-ritankar-bhattacharjee-and-phil).

Comment: No, I've already asked you to [edit] your question to provide an MRE. As it stands, this is not reproducible but I had to guess what some of your implementation looked like ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-burnell-egkirb?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Phil correct you have guessed it right. Now here what happens when you set the institution name inside the react query the value is retained right? and the iput has a default value. But in my component it is not retained. That is what I was asking as to why is this happening

Comment: @Phil I have added all the details that might help you to debug the state behaviour aand edited the complete question

Comment: You really need to pare this back to the absolute **minimal** reproduction. Start with a blank slate and gradually add parts until the problem resurfaces; remove any editing capabilities, remove the reliance on the `allChoices` query

Comment: This is probably solved by this post ~ [Why React useState with functional update form is needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57828368/283366). But that would just be a bandaid on top of what is probably a bad call to `handleFormDataChange()`

Comment: @ I started adding one input at a time and observed that when I use the ckeditor as input field I am starting to have this problem.

Comment: This is practically the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75442200/283366) then and is solved by the same duplicate I linked above.

Comment: @Phil yes phil something similar was happening with me as well and lokking at that answer I figured it out, thanks

Answer (score 0):

So after debugging I founf out that the problem was with the CkEditor component I was using, whose onChange function was creating this behaviour.

the way I was using the onChange function on one of the ckeditor component was like below

```
 <CKEditor
          editor={Editor}
          data={formData.judgements}
          name="judgements"
          id="judgements"
          onChange={(event, editor, e) => {
          const data = editor.getData()
          handleJudgementsData(data)
} }
        />
```

and the onChange function looked like this

```
 const handleJudgementData = (data) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, judgements: data });
  };
```

This was causing the problem as the state was not updating synchronously what I could understand from Phil's answer in the question he linked

so I changed the code in the below way and now it is working

jsx

```
      <CKEditor
          editor={Editor}
          data={formData.judgements}
          onChange={(event, editor, e) => handleJudgementData(event, editor, e)}
        />
```

onChnage function

```
const handleJudgementData = (event, editor) => {
    let data = editor.getData();
    setFormData((prev) => ({ ...prev, judgements: data }));
  };
```

After doing it the above way now the state retains the data fetched from api