# UseState update a single item in object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-hooks, jsx

I have a useState object in my react app that looks like this:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
    soverview: "",
    address: "",
    first_name: "",
    last_name: "",
    email: "",
    phone: "",
    dob: ""
});
```

Throughout my application I have a form and each input has `onChange={handleChange}`.

```
const handleChange = ({ currentTarget: input }) => {
    setData({ ...data, [input.name]: input.value });
};
```

However, I also have a google autocomplete field that allows users to type in their address and have it autofilled out. For that `<Autocomplete/>` field, I have set `onPlaceSelected={(place) => {handleAddress(place)}}`.

```
function handleAddress(place) {
    setData({ ...data, address: place.formatted_address });
}
```

Here is some of my jsx form:

```
<textarea
    className="mb-15"
    name="soverview"
    onChange={handleChange}
    value={data.soverview}
></textarea>

<Autocomplete
    className="mb-30"
    placeholder="Start typing your address"
    apiKey={api_key}
    options={{
        types: ["geocode"],
        componentRestrictions: { country: "aus" },
    }}
    onPlaceSelected={(place) => {
        handleAddress(place)
    }}
/>

<input
    className="mb-15 field-hl p-10-5"
    type="text"
    name="first_name"
    placeholder="John"
    onChange={handleChange}
    value={data.first_name}
    required
/>
```

However, the `...data` does not seem to be working as it clears the `soverview` field which is set initially, and then keeps all the data from `address` onwards. Why is this happening?

Comment: How do you know the `soverview` field is cleared? It's initially an empty string anyway.

Comment: Did you tried `setData(prev => ({ ...data, address: place.formatted_address })); `

Comment: Could the address auto-complete field feature be accidentally triggering a page/form refresh?

Comment: Maybe....? I am using `react-google-autocomplete` @esinator

Comment: @Unmitigated because the soverview field is before the address field. So `onChange` it is setting the value to `data`. Then once the address is set, it seems to clear the soverview field.

Comment: Can you add a little bit of your JSX so we can see how you structured the form components?

Comment: @esinator done! As you can see there are 3 inputs. I tried logging `form` after each change. It seems to be saving `soverview`, but removing it after `address` is updated. After the last input is done, `data` contains everything but `soverview`.

Comment: @devpolo that should be `setData(prev => ({ ...prev, address: place.formatted_address }))`. See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Comment: @Phil is right! That fixes it