# Do i have to delete the event listener manually in websockets?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

Does the following code create duplicate `on.message` listeners ?
when i execute `on.message` once, the payloads array takes it's initial value each time

```
export default function ProjectChat() {

    const { id: projectId } = useParams()

    const [payloads, setPayloads] = useState([])
    const [messageBody, setMessageBody] = useState('')
    const [webSocket, setWebSocket] = useState(null)

    // Create the connection
    useEffect(() => {
        const url = `ws://localhost:3000/ws/${projectId}`;
        const ws = new WebSocket(url);
        setWebSocket(ws)

        return () => ws.close()
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (webSocket !== null) {
            webSocket.onmessage = e => {
                const payload = JSON.parse(e.data);
                const allMessages = [...payloads, payload]
                setPayloads(allMessages)
            }
        }
    }, [webSocket, payloads])

    return <p>jsx</p>
}
```

Comment: Try using [functional update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57828368/why-react-usestate-with-functional-update-form-is-needed) and remove `payloads` from deps array: `setPayloads(curr => [...curr, ...payload])`

Answer (score 0):

You can't create duplicate listeners with `on.message`. Every time you define `on.message`, you're over-writing the previous listener.

The `addListener` is the method which can lead to multiple [listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket#examples). In that case, you would want to run [removeEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) on the listener you created inside your component's unmount phase `return () => removeEvenListener(...)`.