# will a fast consecutive click result in bugs in updating state in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

based on the https://stackoverflow.com/a/73115899/21769004 and the example from https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html, below is valid code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

What if I click the button twice very quickly, so first click calls `setCount(count + 1)` and because React's state change apply asynchronously, so `count` is still 0 (after the first click) at the moment, then I click the button again within 5 millisecond, and the second click calls `setCount(count + 1)`, since the first update hasn't been applied, so the `count` still 0, and the second click uses the stale `count` value, therefore it shows "You clicked 1 times" instead of "You clicked 2 times".

Is my understand correct? is the reason that we still get correct results because we cannot make a consecutive click within tiny millisecond, but theoretically if we can make consecutive clicks faster enough then the code could be a bug?

Comment: Are you programmatically firing the click?

Comment: That's why you should use the callback version of setState,  `setCount(c => c + 1)`,

Comment: @Keith but the react hooks's offical docs doesn't use the callback, and based on the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73115899/21769004, it doesn't need to use callback for a single handler call

Comment: @evolutionxbox no, but it doesn't sound right when the arise of bugs depends on how fast you click the button

Comment: Regardless, the callback version takes scope out of the equation.. And if your like me, I like to refactor, so not having to worry about scope is a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

The React take care of this using **Batching**.

Batching in React describes the internal implementation detail of React which treats multiple state updates as one state update. The benefit: multiple state updates are batched as one state update and therefore trigger only one re-rendering of the component which improves the rendering performance.

So, without batching, frequent clicks can lead to unnecessary re-renders and potentially incorrect UI display in certain scenarios. It can also result in performance issues and reduced efficiency.

You can read more about this concept [here](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-batching/).