# incorrect array length when updated with React.useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, html5-canvas

I am writing a react app to draw some points on canvas.
The points are managed by `React.useState`.

Here are the main components of the program:

```
class Point {
    x: number;
    y: number;

    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y
    }
}
```

```
    const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);
    const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = React.useState([] as Point[]);
```

```
        <div>
            <input type={"file"} accept={"image/png, image/jpeg"} onChange={handleFileUpload}/>
            <button onClick={handleProcess}>Process</button>
            <br/>
            <canvas ref={canvasRef} width={240} height={240} onClick={handleCanvasClick}/>
      </div>
```

```
    function handleCanvasClick(e: any) {
        const canvas = canvasRef.current;
        if (!canvas) {
            return
        }
        const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        const x = e.clientX - rect.left;
        const y = e.clientY - rect.top;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx!.fillStyle = 'red';
        ctx!.fillRect(x, y, 5, 5);
        const point = new Point(x, y);
        setCoordinates([...coordinates, point])

        console.log(coordinates.length)
    }
```

I found that the points can be correctly drawn on the canvas, however, the length of `coordinates` is not expected.
For example:
[image]

Here two points are drawn, but the output of `console.log(coordinates.length)` is only 1. Shouldn't it be 2? Is there anything I missed here when React hooks update the value?

Comment: Also see [Why React useState with functional update form is needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57828368/283366). Basically you want `setCoordinates((prev) => [...prev, point]);` and why bother logging the length?

Comment: Pretend the method `setState` is called `setStateOnNextRender`. TS tip: I think you can do `const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')!;` so you don't have to `ctx!.` over and over.